# array not getting values

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running a script that changes values in a formula with a message box.

```
var searchtext = Browser.inputBox("Enter search text");
var replacetext = Browser.inputBox("Enter replace text");
var form = ss1.getRange("D3");
var formula = form.getFormula();
var updated =formula;
updated.indexOf(searchtext);
updated = updated.replace(searchtext, replacetext);
form.setFormula(updated);

var form2 = ss1.getRange("D10");
var formula2 = form2.getFormula();
var updated2 =formula2;
updated2.indexOf(searchtext);
updated2 = updated2.replace(searchtext, replacetext);
form2.setFormula(updated2);
```

As you notice I have to repeat the code for the different ranges I have. In the code above I have D3 and D10 ranges. I have around another 20 ranges that I need to replace formula from. I have created this array to hopefully do them all together while the script runs but I am not seeing any changes. Any ideas why would this be happening?

```
  function dash(){
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var searchtext = Browser.inputBox("Enter search text");
var replacetext = Browser.inputBox("Enter replace text");

var rangeArray =     ss1.setActiveSheet(ss1.getSheetByName("Ranges").getRange("A1:A5").getValues());
var daily = ss1.setActiveSheet(ss1.getSheetByName("Daily"));

for(var i in rangeArray){
var form = daily.getRange(rangeArray[i][0]);

var formula = getRange(form).getFormula();
var updated =formula;
updated.indexOf(searchtext);
updated = updated.replace(searchtext, replacetext);
form.setFormula(updated);}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few informtion about your sheet layout that I ignore so I had to make some assumptions...
I suppose the ranges you want to process are columns in the sheet so I would do something like this (see comments in code): (I didn't have the opportunity to test this code, it might need some debugging)

```
function dash(){
    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var searchtext = Browser.inputBox("Enter search text");
    var replacetext = Browser.inputBox("Enter replace text");
    var rangeArray = ss1.getSheetByName("Ranges").getRange("A1:A4").getValues(); // I suppose these cells contains A1 notation of the useful ranges
    var daily = ss1.setActiveSheet(ss1.getSheetByName("Daily"));
Logger.log(rangeArray)
    for(var i in rangeArray){
    var formula = daily.getRange(rangeArray[i][0].toString()).getFormula();//
Logger.log(formula)
    var updated =formula.toString().replace(searchtext, replacetext);
Logger.log(updated)    
}
    daily.getRange(rangeArray[i][0].toString()).setFormula(updated);//
}
```

EDIT : removed first code and replaced following your comment and example sheet

Comment: there where a few typos in the first version, now it should be ok (sorry about that if you tried it)

Comment: It's okay, I am actually trying to run it right now but still no luck. When I try to debug it I get google error message that says Server temporarily down. I am sharing the spreadsheet where I am doing the testing so you can have a better idea,https://docs.google.com/a/infolinksa.net/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgIoLd4RqjMXdFJDYXQxM05oaE9LYXFzUGtHS1NUTXc#gid=0

Comment: thanks, it is indeed easier like this ;-) see updated code, it becomes simpler and shorter

Comment: I tried the updated code, but it is only changing the last range while leaving intact the others? Why do you think this happens?

Comment: I tried on a test sheet and it processed all ranges... strange... I'll test again and come back here with my results

Comment: Hey I think I found out the problem. This part of the code "daily.getRange(rangeArray[i][0].toString()).setFormula(updated);" needed to go inside the for loop. It is working now. Thanks once again Serge